# Standard algorithm or pattern to read huge data in parallel using JDBC in Java application

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, jdbc

Below is a simple program which reads data from MySQL and stores in a CSV file. If the query returns over 10 million records its going to be slow.

I totally understand that to do in parallel we need do process like

1. Get the record count from the query ( select * from users )
2. Then break the query in to parallel chunk with appropriate ( select * from users where state = 'CA' )
3. Then data can be read in parallel in 50 threads or distributed across process.

Apache spark uses partition_column with lower-upper bound and number of partition as shown below.

I'm curious to know if there is a way/pattern/algorithm that can be used in Non-Spark application to get huge data in parallel. However I'll look at Spark code for the below implementation.

https://medium.com/@radek.strnad/tips-for-using-jdbc-in-apache-spark-sql-396ea7b2e3d3

```
spark.read("jdbc")
  .option("url", url)
  .option("dbtable", "pets")
  .option("user", user)
  .option("password", password)
  .option("numPartitions", 10)
  .option("partitionColumn", "owner_id")
  .option("lowerBound", 1)
  .option("upperBound", 10000)
  .load()

SELECT * FROM pets WHERE owner_id >= 1 and owner_id < 1000
SELECT * FROM pets WHERE owner_id >= 1000 and owner_id < 2000
SELECT * FROM pets WHERE owner_id >= 2000 and owner_id < 3000
```

Simple MySQL code to read and store data in CSV file

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
        String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
        Class.forName(myDriver);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "");
        String query = "SELECT * FROM users";
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (rs.next())
        {
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String firstName = rs.getString("first_name");
            String lastName = rs.getString("last_name");
            Date dateCreated = rs.getDate("date_created");
            boolean isAdmin = rs.getBoolean("is_admin");
            int numPoints = rs.getInt("num_points");
            sb.append(String.format("%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s\n", id, firstName, lastName, dateCreated, isAdmin, numPoints));
        }

        try (FileOutputStream oS = new FileOutputStream(new File("aFile.csv"))) {
            oS.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        st.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Lookup the LIMIT clause for a select statement. You could execute the same statement multiple times with a LIMIT 0,10000 on the first, then LIMIT 10000,10000 on the 2nd, LIMIT 20000,10000 on the 3rd, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't precisely answer your question, but [`SELECT DATA INTO OUTFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) may help you export your data rapidly.

Here's an example of the command to generate a CSV file in your case,

```
SELECT * 
  INTO OUTFILE '/some/path/to/users.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM users;
```

This uses a fast path to write data to your filesystem and may be faster than your threaded approach. It is *certainly* easier to program.

It's always a good idea to precede such a high-volume query with `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;` to avoid blocking inserts and updates to the table.

If you will use multiple Java threads to retrieve your data, I suggest you use this strategy:

1. Before spawning threads, determine the largest `id` value by doing this query:  `SELECT MAX(id) FROM users;`
2. Decide how many threads you will spawn. Too many threads will be counterproductive, because they will overload your MySQL server. Fifty threads is **far** too many connections to your MySQL server. Use four or eight.
3. Give each thread its own segment of `id` values to retrieve. For example, if you had ten million rows and four threads, the segments would be [1-2500000], [2500001-5000000], [5000001-7500000], and [7500001-10000000].
4. In each thread, open a jdbc connection to MySQL, and do `WHERE id BETWEEN segmentstart AND segmentfinish` to choose the right rows. (MySQL connections are not thread-safe objects).
5. Put `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;` before your SELECT queries.

`id` is (presumably) the primary key of the `users` table, so the `WHERE` filtering using it will be very efficient.